# Array in java to print only needed data in java

Tags: arrays

I need to print the list of data where id is S123

```
alist.add(new Student ("XYZ", 25, "123 Street Name", "S123"));
        alist.add(new staff("ACS", 45, "1235 fasho street", "R123"));
        alist.add(new Student("ACBB", 55, "1235 fasho street", "S234"));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And the question is? What have you tried? Do you know about the existence of the allmighty for loop?

Comment: I want to print Student array where student ID is S123

Answer (score 0):

Why not have simply use .contains on a list?

Something like:

```
String match [] = Arrays.asList(alist).contains("S123");
```

Comment: do we need to declare match to boolean?

Comment: Boolean would just return true or false for a given match. If the match is found it will return True else False. If you want student data for a match simply use for loop and if id = S123 then store that data in a array and print it once exit the loop. or simply use what I showed. String match []. This will store a data for a given match